# How to handle Access table with column names with spaces?

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table and column name both have spaces in them.  I am trying to simply fill in some null values. I used the same template to update another column in this table, but it did not have spaces in the column name as well. Does anyone know what I need to do to handle the column names correctly?

```
UPDATE [Fund Buckets]

SET 'Global Baskets' = IIf(IsNull('Global Baskets'), "GBS", 'Global Baskets')

WHERE 'Global Baskets' Is Null;
```

Comment: What RDBMS?  Is `Global Baskets` a column name?

Comment: Yea Global baskets is a column name

Comment: If it is MS Access then use square brackets SELECT [table 1].[field 1]
FROM [table 1]

Comment: But I need to update the table not select the missing values?

Comment: UPDATE [Fund Buckets]

SET [Fund Buckets].[Global Baskets] = IIf(IsNull([Fund Buckets].[Global Baskets]), 'GBS', [Fund Buckets].[Global Baskets])

WHERE [Fund Buckets]. [Global Baskets] Is Null;

Answer (score 1):

You still need to reference field to compare its values. Field name between apostrophes is just literal text. `'Global Baskets'` is certainly not Null - it is a string.

Use brackets to define objects that have space or other non-alpha characters (only exception is underscore) in name.

Filter criteria is only pulling records where [Global Baskets] Is Null so IIf() is redundant, i.e., it is not needed unless you remove WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE [Fund Buckets]
SET [Global Baskets] = 'GBS'
WHERE [Global Baskets] Is Null;
```

Comment: This was what I initally tried, but it asks me to "Enter Paramater Value" so then I went the direction of what I mentioned initially

Comment: If it asks for parameter then it does not recognize field name.

Comment: How do i get it to recornize it?

Comment: Usually means not spelled correctly.

Comment: I tihnk the issue is the field name has spaces

Comment: The brackets handle that. I have no problem with space when brackets are used. Something else is wrong. Could post in a discussion forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.